# Pytorch silent data corruption

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am on a workstation with 4 A6000 GPUs. Moving a Torch tensor from one GPU to another GPU corrupts the data, silently!!!

See the simple example below.

```
x
>tensor([1], device='cuda:0')

x.to(1)
>tensor([1], device='cuda:1')

x.to(2)
>tensor([0], device='cuda:2')

x.to(3)
>tensor([0], device='cuda:3')
```

Any ideas what is the cause of this issue?

Other info that might be handy:

(there was two nvlinks which I manually removed trying to solve the problem)

```
        GPU0    GPU1    GPU2    GPU3    CPU Affinity    NUMA Affinity
GPU0     X      SYS     SYS     SYS     0-63            N/A
GPU1    SYS      X      SYS     SYS     0-63            N/A
GPU2    SYS     SYS      X      SYS     0-63            N/A
GPU3    SYS     SYS     SYS      X      0-63            N/A
```

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Mar__8_18:18:20_PST_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.124
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.31057947_0
```

```
NVIDIA-SMI 510.47.03    Driver Version: 510.47.03    CUDA Version: 11.6
```

Edit: adding some screenshots

It seems to be stateful. Changes which GPUs work fine together after starting a new python runtime.

[image: It seems to be stateful, changes which GPUs work fine together after starting a new python runtime.]

Comment: Is it repeatable? What dtype is your tensor? Does it also happen if you use `to('cuda:1')` etc instead of just the number?

Comment: dtype here is int, but persists with float too.
Yes, it's repeatable (persists after shutting down).
Yes, it still gets corrupted even with to('cuda:1'). 

Trying multiple other things something more strange comes up too (adding it as an image to the question.)

Comment: Can you add an example using a longer tensor? This might give some kind of signal as to what exactly is going on (eg., maybe the entire tensor on 2 and 3 gets converted to 0).

Comment: You might also consider directly reporting this as a bug on the [Pytorch GitHub](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch). If you do so, be sure **not** to delete it here on SO as it may be useful to future users, especially if you follow up with the resolution to the bug here.

Comment: Yes, same issue with longer tensors too. See this for a screenshot of a longer tensor https://snipboard.io/FaOG2g.jpg

Comment: @Kraigolas, thanks for the suggestion. Reported the issue on PyTorch GitHub too. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/84803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to disable IOMMU. On our server, in the BIOS settings

`/Advanced/AMD CBS/NBIO Common Options/IOMMU -> IOMMU - Disabled`

See the [PyTorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/84803) issues thread for more information.